# zoom and crop a map with tmap

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I am trying to prepare an inset map to give a reference of the geographic location of Bhutan. I would like a map that fills the box, in which part of India, China, Bangladesh are visible and NOT the whole Asian continent.

I am using the following code:

```
library(tmap); library(tidyverse)
data("World")
Asia<-World%>%filter(continent %in% c("Asia"))
Asia$isBhutan <- ifelse(Asia$name=="Bhutan", "darkorange", "grey")
tm_shape(Asia)+tm_fill("isBhutan")+tm_polygons()
```

I expect to zoom and crop this map to make Bhutan more visible. India, China, Bangladesh, Nepal are enough reference for Bhutan's location. I would like the map to fill the box, leaving Bhutan at the center.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a bounding box with the `sf` package. You can then use this in your `tmap`.

For example (adding to your code):

```
# create a bounding box on Bhutan and others
# play around with the countries to get what you want
library(sf)
bhu_bb <- st_bbox(World %>% filter(name %in% c("Bhutan", "India", "China", "Nepal")))

#new tmap with bbox
tm_shape(Asia, bbox = bhu_bb) + 
  tm_fill("isBhutan") + 
  tm_polygons()
```

This is still a large area as the India and China are large, but you can set the `bbox` coordinates manually too.